# how to use these functions to draw lines and arcs using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code given to me:

```
def line(points=[], color="hotpink", **kwargs):
    return the_canvas.create_line(points, fill=color, **kwargs)


def arc(points=[], width=5, color="hotpink", line_steps=15, **kwargs):
    the_canvas.create_line(
        points,  # tuple of x-y pairs
        width=width,
        fill=color,
        splinesteps=line_steps,
        smooth=True,
        **kwargs
    )
```

I was supposed to call the line and the arc function, and I tried:
`line(points=[1], "red"), line([1]), line(1), line("red")`, but none of these worked.

How do I use these functions?

Comment: What were you expecting any of those calls to *do*?  Where do you expect the line to appear on the screen, when you're only supplying one number for its coordinates?

Comment: @jasonharper ahhh okay i tried line([(0,100), (100,500)]) and it drew a line, thank you!